# Why subsequent dynamically linked function calls need an extra indirection through the PLT?

Tags: shared-libraries, x86-64, elf, dynamic-linking

Lets say I have a program called `P` which is linked dynamically with a library. When calling a function which is in a shared library which was compiled with `-fPIC` as I understand these things happen

1. There is something like `call functionName@plt` in `P`
2. This then jumps to the `PLT` table code to the appropriate entry
3. From there we jump to where the respective `GOT` entry points
4. If this is the first call of this function then this is the moment when the binding starts to happen and the `GOT` entry will point us back to the `PLT` entry at the binding code
5. So the binding code then finds the address of the function and puts the address value to the `GOT` entry and runs it

The `GOT` entry stores an address which either is to the binding code in the respective `PLT` entry if the function hasn't been called yet or it points to the `functionName` code address. My question is why in P at the calling point in step 1 isn't there something like `call [functionName@GOT]`.

Meaning to load the value of the `GOT` entry and jump directly there. This will give  one less indirection for each call of this function other than the first one. If it is the first call it will jump to the `PLT` binding code, the binding will happen and the `GOT`'s value will be updated. Subsequent calls will point directly to the function code because now the `GOT` entry points to the function.

One suspicion is because of the ability to take the address of the function. Is it right?

Answer (score 0):

> If it is the first call it will jump to the PLT binding code, the binding will happen and the GOT's value will be updated.

How will the PLT binding code know what function to look up?

On first call, the PLT stub [sets up parameters to the resolver](http://eli.thegreenplace.net/2011/11/03/position-independent-code-pic-in-shared-libraries), and these parameters are different for *each* PLT stub (which is why you need one PLT stub for each imported function).

Comment: You mean the part in the article that says "Preparation of arguments for a "resolver" routine"? If yes then isn't the address that the GOT entry initially points to, the first instruction of this preparation code, which in turn sets up the parameters?